# Are there any async Python libraries without implicit callback chaining?

Tags: python, asynchronous, promise

Python and Twisted have various flavors of objects representing non-blocking execution, typically called Futures or Deferreds. They all tend to use *implicit callback chaining* semantics. That is, if you have some `deferred` and add two callbacks like so:

```
deferred.add_callback(callback1)
deferred.add_callback(callback2)
```

Then `callback1` will get whatever value the deferred resolves to, but `callback2` won't - it will get whatever `callback1` returns. This can be difficult to reason about, especially if the two callbacks are added to the deferred at different places in your code. I'd prefer if chaining had to be explicit, like this:

```
new_deferred = deferred.add_callback(callback1)
new_deferred.add_callback(callback2)
```

This is how Javascript promises work, and I find it's much easier to reason about. Are there any asynchronous Python libraries that work this way?

Comment: The `Future` objects in `tornado` and `asyncio` don't have implicit callback chaining, but they also don't support explicit callback chaining like in your example, either. Both frameworks favor using coroutines over callbacks in general, actually.

Comment: https://github.com/xogeny/aplus